# Dar preferencia aos resultados que possui o parâmetro passado no Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Estou tentando implementar uma solução de dados que exibe primeiro os valores que possui o parâmetro passado para depois passar os demais parâmetros.

Exemplo:

Em uma tabela de produtos possui os seguintes dados:

```
Coca-Cola  -> Coca Cola Company
Pepsi      -> Pepsico
Toddy      -> Pepsico
Dolly      -> Dolly
Itubaina   -> Schin
```

Quando eu passa o parâmetro o fabricante "Pepsico" no entity Framework ele deve exibir os valores na seguinte ordem:

```
Pepsi      -> Pepsico
Toddy      -> Pepsico
Coca-Cola  -> Coca Cola Company
Dolly      -> Dolly
Itubaina   -> Schin
```

Como posso fazer isto?

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer?

Comment: Realizar duas pesquisar, uma para pegar os dados do parâmetro e a outra para os demais dados, mas queria algo mais eficiênte

Comment: Sim, mas como esta isso?

Comment: var lista = Produtos.Where(x=> x.Fabricante == "Pepsico").toList(); var listaSemParametros = Produtos.Where(x=> x.Fabricante != "Pepsico").toList(); após isto eu uno as duas listas

Comment: @GustavoCorreiaSantos, existem dois tipos de ordenação, por ascendência e descendência. Por que você quer fazer essa ordenação ? Por um acaso "Pepsico" é o produto mais vendido ?

Comment: é apenas um exemplo de parâmetro que o usuário passa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer dessa maneira:

```
var result = Produtos.OrderByDescending(e => e.Fabricante.Contains("Pepsico"));
```